# search data not being displayed after search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have installed ransack and it seems easy to use. However when I click search it just refreshes the page, the proper data is not shown. On the page I have the search box with listing all registered usernames (admin and user). For the search box I entered 'admin' and when I click search the page reloads and I continue to see all registered users (admin and user). It should be displaying 'admin' only after the search. Any idea as to why this is happening?

users_controller:

```
  def index
     @search = User.search(params[:q])
     @users = @search.result
     @users = User.all
   end
```

index.html:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username_cont, "Name contains" %>
    <%= f.text_field :username_cont %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
<% end %>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
       <%= link_to user.username, user %>
        <% if current_user.admin? || current_user == @user %>
            <%= link_to "Edit #{user} profile", user %>
            | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                          data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>
        <% end %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting all the results not search results...   You are over-riding the instance variable

this:

```
@users = @search.result
@users = User.all
```

should just be:

```
@users = @search.result
```

or better yet:

```
@search = User.search(params[:q])
if params[:q].present?
  @users = @search.result
else
  @users = User.all
end
```

All being said...  Is your form submitting a param for "q"?  I don't know ransack but I think your form also needed changing.

Comment: I figured it was something with user.all and of course I couldn't remove it. I just didn't know what to do with it. Simple fix. Tho I don't understand the if params present part you added. Will have to look into that to see what the difference is what that added.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the search results with `@user = User.all`. Delete that line.

Your form is probably ok since that's the ransack builder you're using and you said it comes back to the current page. When it comes back to the current page do you see `http://localhost:3000/users?q= (search parameters here)` in the url?